# PS script errors in first run: The object of type ".PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence

Tags: powershell

I have the following function that works correctly in 2012r2, when i run it in 2008R2 it throws the below error. The surprising thing is that if i execute it a second time, it works without any issue!!

```
# Function Reg-Stamp {
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]$Phase
)

$msg = "`nEntering: $((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value.MyCommand.Name)" ;     Write-Host -fore Gray $msg ; $msg | out-file -Append $log


$RegStampInfo = Build-Variable $RegStampCSV


$Version = ($ScriptVersionInfo | Where-Object {$_.Parameter -eq "Version" -and $_.Phase  -eq $Phase }).Value
$DisplayName = ($ScriptVersionInfo | Where-Object {$_.Parameter -eq "DisplayName" -and     $_.Phase -eq $Phase }).Value
$BuildDate = ($ScriptVersionInfo | Where-Object {$_.Parameter -eq "BuildDate" -and $_.Phase -eq $Phase }).Value
$RunDate = Get-Date
$Success = $(-not($CriticalError))

$msg = "`nUpdating registry with build information"; Write-Host -fore Gray $msg; $msg | out-file $log -Append;

$RegStampInfo | Where-Object {($_.Phase.ToLower()) -eq ($Phase.ToLower())} | foreach-Object {

$ValueData = $(get-variable -Name $($_.StampData) -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
$msg = "Adding Key: $($_.StampKey) '$($_.StampValue)' '$ValueData'"; Write-Host -fore Green "$msg"; $msg | out-file $log -Append;

New-Item -Path $($_.StampKey) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.StampKey -name $_.StampValue -Value $ValueData

}

$msg = "`nExiting: $((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value.MyCommand.Name)"; Write-Host -fore DarkGreen  $msg ; $msg | out-file -Append $log

    #}
```

I get the following error:

```
out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.For
mat.FormatStartData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likel
y caused by a user-specified "format-table" command which is conflicting with t
he default formatting.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], InvalidOperat
   ionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.P
   owerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

I have seen similar error in powershell when using format-table however i am not using fr here atleast directly.
Not sure what is wrong!

EDIT:
no, but it turns out that the issue was not in the above script at all. 
It appears that caller script had a line involving format-table which had nothing to do with this script, was causing the issue.

```
$SupportFilesInfo = Import-csv $SupportFilesCSV | select-object
$SupportFilesInfo | ft ; $SupportFilesInfo | Out-File -append $log
```

I changed it to:

```
$SupportFilesInfo | ft | out-default; $SupportFilesInfo | Out-File -append $log
```

which resolved the error!!

However i am still at loss at why the error occurs ONLY during the first run. 
I had hit this issue earlier too, but it was very consistent.
Any idea why?

Comment: do you get the line number of error?

Comment: no, but it turns out that the issue was not in the above script at all. it appears that caller script had a line involving format-table which had nothing to do with this script, was causing the issue. $SupportFilesInfo = Import-csv $SupportFilesCSV | select-object
$SupportFilesInfo | ft ; $SupportFilesInfo | Out-File -append $log

Comment: makes sense, that's why I asked for the line #, as nothing seemed out of ordinary.

Comment: thanks, but would you know why it would occur the very first time. Every other time i saw this type of error, it was consistently occurring every time.

Comment: Not without seeing your code